# Como pegar o retorno de uma procedure para saber se teve alguma linha afetada?

Tags: asp.net-core

Minha dúvida é saber se teve alguma linha afetada na execução dessa *procedure* e armazenar o resultado em uma variável do tipo `int`.

**Caso for = 0**, parar o processo.

**Caso for > 0**, seguir com o processo.

Tenho os seguintes códigos:

Controller:

```
   public void InserirSaldoBonusExtrato(PCINET.pciPedidos.PedidoVenda pedido)
        {
            try
            {
                Extrato extrato = new Extrato(config);
                extrato.Cliente = pedido.PedCliente;
                extrato.Valor = pedido.PedValor;
                extrato.Ciclo = pedido.PedCiclo;
                extrato.TpOperCodigo = 9;
                extrato.TpOperNome = "Pgtopedido";
                extrato.Descricao = "Pagamento do pedido " + pedido.PedNumero + " com bônus";
                extrato.Indicante = 0;
                extrato.Pendente = "N";
                extrato.InserirSaldoBonusExtrato();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Model:

```
 public void InserirSaldoBonusExtrato()
    {
        try
        {
            new ExtratoDB(config).InserirSaldoBonus(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Dapper(data):

```
   public void InserirSaldoBonus(Extrato extrato)
    {

        try
        {
            var db = new Data<Extrato>(config);
            string query = @"sp_InsereSaldoBonusExtrato @Cliente, @Valor, @Ciclo, @TpOperCodigo, @TpOperNome, @Descricao, @Indicante, @Pendente";
            db.Executar(query, extrato);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois pontos para verificar:

**1**. A *stored procedure* está retornando o número de registros afetados?

Você deve executar a *procedure* e se certificar que ela retorna o número de registros afetados. Por exemplo, em `SQL Server`, deve ser setado `SET NOCOUNT OFF` para executar a *procedure*, senão não é retornado. Você pode também retornar o valor por si próprio, como por exemplo, em `SQL Server` usando a variável `@@ROWCOUNT` que retorna o número de linhas afetadas

**2**. Está tratando o retorno?

No seu código, a linha que executa a *procedure* é essa:
`db.Executar(query, extrato)` mas não vejo o retorno dessa chamada, algo como `var total = db.Executar(query, extrato)`. Se não tratar o retorno assim, ou com um parâmetro de *output*, mesmo que a *procedure* retorne você não vai ter esse valor.